# If the scalar triple product of three vectors is zero, must the plane they lie in pass through the origin?

Tags: vector-spaces

$[x,y,z]=0$ implies that the three vectors are coplanar but I don't see why it has to pass through the origin. Are there any counterexamples for this?

Answer (score 0):

If your vectors have their origin at the origin of the coordinate system, then it has to pass through the origin.  The first two vectors (with origin $(0,0,0)$) determine a plane.  The third is in this plane.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see it - the equation of a plane through three given vectors is:
$$\Bigg[\vec{r} - \vec{a}, \vec{r} - \vec{b}, \vec{r} - \vec{c}\Bigg] = 0$$

Set $\vec{r}$ as the origin and use the condition $[\vec a, \vec b, \vec c] = 0$ to check if it passes through the origin.